# Axios cancel works for every page

Tags: axios

I create an axios instance like this:

```js
export const requestController = new AbortController();

const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/v1`,
  signal: requestController.signal,
});
```

And in my home page I have useEffect to fetch data and cancel requests when unmount

```js
const MainPage = () => {
....
useEffect(() => {
   httpClient.get(...)
   httpClient.get(...)
   httpClient.get(...)

    return () => {
      requestController.abort();
    };
}, [])
}
```

But then requests in other pages stop working too. Even if I cancelled request in one page. How to fix it?
Update: Yes I know that I could just use controller only where I need. But I need more common solution so that it could work for every unmounted component - cancel requests. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seemingly are using the very same instance of the `AbortController` for *every* request (because it's set on the default `httpClient`), so yes, of course, signalling it, would cancel every request issued by that `httpClient`. You should remove the `signal` from the default client and create an `AbortController` for every request you need to cancel and pass it to that specific request. This way, only this specific request will be aborted ...

```
useEffect(() => {
   let ueAbortController = new AbortController();
   httpClient.get(url1, { signal: ueAbortController.signal} )
   httpClient.get(url2)
   httpClient.get(url3, { signal: ueAbortController.signal} )

    return () => {
      ueAbortController.abort();
    };
}, [])
```

Just for demonstration purposes, in the snippet above only requests to `url1` and `url3` will be aborted, but not the request to `url2`, because it doesn't have an abortion signal set ...

Comment: Yes, but my lead said I should make it for every page. To cancel request on every unmount. And do not send controlle for every request. So I needed more abstract solution.

Comment: Then you may create a own `httpClient` for every component/page and and set a default `AbortController` for that client. This will then abort all requests for that client on onmount but not interfere with requests on other pages ...